# Android Adapter View Read Onclick Item

Tags: android

I have wrote a code for read onclick item on android adapter view,

```
String s = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
```

and I am passing that s using

```
i.putExtra("myvalues", s);
```

On my second class page display this output like this:

{description=description about selected, title=selected title}

I just want to know how display description and title separately.

eg:

Selected Title ( display on one TextView )
description about selected ( display on another TextView)

--- class one ------------

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

```
        String s = (lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

        Intent i=new Intent(PageOne.this, PageTwo.class);
        i.putExtra("name", s);
        startActivity(i);



    }
```

----------------- page two ------------------

I am catch that value:

```
TextView Textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.singleidview);
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    String j = (String) b.get("name");
    Textv.setText(j);
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit more

Comment: Show us your adapter.

Comment: so use custom adapter with your custom layout for each row (they need to have 2 textviews if you want to set values in different textviews)

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic so, how to split that {description=description about selected, title=selected title} value for two textviews, Is there any better solution than String parts[] = yourstring.split(",");

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking about this

```
       String parts[] = yourstring.split(",");

      parts[0] gives first string as description set this in first textview
       parts[1] gives your title set this in second textview
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but if we split using "," parts[0] =  {description=description about selected  .. that mean it should split again to reach that output

Comment: use replace instead of split in next step means use replace("description=","");
that means replace string with blank string